# Print div with external css using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want print html div with external css, where I am loading external font,the div is content editable div, I did it using jQuery but I want to use AngularJs.

```js
<script>
function printContent(el){
var restorepage = $('body').html();
var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();
$('body').empty().html(printcontent);
window.print(); 
$('body').html(restorepage);
}
</script>
```

```css
#test {
 color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printContent('test')"> Print</button>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">ADCDDDDDSSS</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access particular DOM element by using <kbd>[angular.element.find](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)</kbd>

```
angular.element.find('test');
console.log(t.html().text())
```

similar way you can set html of selected DOM to `body` and print it as per your requirement.

Comment: "console.log(t.html().text())" what is "t" here?

Comment: thats just temporary variable who store the output of `angular.element.find('test');`